# Windows 10 setup stuck at "Just a Moment"

Tags: windows-10, windows-installation, delay

I'm in the process of installing Windows 10 for someone, on a 500 GB SSD that I formatted as part of the installation. Everything was going smoothly, I rebooted, entered the next phase of installation, selected some locale-related settings... and then Windows told me "Just a moment".

30 minutes later, I'm still waiting.

Questions:

1. Why is this happening?
2. What should I do about this? Restart the machine? Something else?

Having switched to Linux several years back, I'm not used to this particular annoyance :-(

Notes:

- If you need additional details about my system, please ask in the comments.
- Related, but focus on another point: [Windows 10 installation stuck at Just a moment](https://superuser.com/q/1543724/122798)

Answer (score 3):

A partial answer:

I found a post on a [Microsoft support website](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-stuck-on-just-a-moment-cant-do-anything/f7a45a56-aed0-4a73-ac6c-788c0eb164ff) supporting my speculation that power-cycling could work. So, following it, here's what I did exactly:

1. Powered the machine down with a long press on the power button.
2. Removed the Windows installation media (in my case, the flash drive).
3. Powered the machine back up.
4. Entered the UEFI boot menu.
5. Chose the apparently-newly-installed boot manager on the SSD.

I got that blue-perspective-windows logo for a while, then I arrived again at the "Just a Moment" screen. But a second or so later, the installation continued to checking for updates, or what's new on the network, or something like that, and continued from there on with a couple more settings it wanted to have me make.

I can't guarantee that this will work for everybody in this situation, but - that's my experience. Better than waiting indefinitely.

Also - I have no idea why this happened!

Answer (score 0):

One issue could be the bootable USB - I personally use the media creation tool (https://www.microsoft.com/ro-ro/software-download/windows10) so I can install Windows 10 on either a UEFI or Legacy BIOS.

Comment: Why would that be an issue, if the setup booted and ran and copied files etc.?

Comment: I have no idea except that in my case I solve that by using a bootable USB made with Windows media creation tool. No more "Just a moment" freezing screen.